# Password never works in PHP login system

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am trying to set up a PHP members area on my web server, which has hashed and salted passwords. I registered an account and checked the database - the user is created as expected - everything seemed fine. The problem is whenever I try to log in it says the login is incorrect (username or password). Of course this is being done in a test area, and the user name and password I registered with should work - but doesn't.

**auth.php:** should authenticate the user and create a session if the details are valid
//login never works

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (strlen($username)<3 || strlen($password)<3) {
    header('Location: log_in.php5?error=1');
    die();
}

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

function validateUser() {
    session_regenerate_id ();
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $username;
}

include "../db_login.php5";
mysql_select_db("DB_NAME", $con);

$query = "SELECT password, salt
        FROM users
        WHERE username = '" . $username . "';";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$userData = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$count = mysql_num_rows($userData);

if ($count < 1) {
    header('Location: log_in.php5?error=1');
    die();
}

$salt = "";
$hashed_pass = "";

for ($x=0; $x<1; $x++) {
  $salt = $userData['salt'];
  $hashed_pass = $userData['password'];
}

$hash = hash('sha256', $salt . hash('sha256', $password));

mysql_close($con);

if ($hash != $hashed_pass) {
    header('Location: log_in.php5?error=1');
    die();
} else {
    validateUser();
}

header('Location: members.php5');
?>
```

**register.php:** should take the username, hash the password with a salt, store all 3 to DB //works

```
<?php
//retrieve our data from POST
$username = $_POST['username'];
$pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
if($pass1 != $pass2)
    header('Location: sign_up.php5');
if(strlen($username) > 30)
    header('Location: sign_up.php5');

$hash = hash('sha256', $pass1);

function createSalt(){
    $string = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    return substr($string, 0, 3);
}

$salt = createSalt();
$hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);

include "../db_register.php5";
mysql_select_db("DB_NAME", $con);

//sanitize username
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, salt)
        VALUES ( '$username' , '$hash' , '$salt' );";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close($con);

header('Location: log_in.php5');
?>
```

The **login.php** file is a simple form which posts the data to auth.php;
the **sign_up.php** file is also a simple form which posts the user data to register.php.

**What is wrong with my code that it wont allow me to log in?**

EDIT:

So I've narrowed the problem down so the $username variable which seems to be blank from the start?

output:

```
Count: 
User: 
Query: SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='';
```

code for output:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `username`='".$username."';";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$userData = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$count = mysql_num_rows($userData);

if ($count < 1) {
    echo "Count: ".$count."<BR/>"
    . "User: " .$username ."<BR/>"
    . "Query: " .$query;
    //header('Location: log_in.php5?error=1,count='.$count.'user='.$username);
    //die();
}
```

$count and $username are not printed in either Address nor the sql query

**EDIT 2:**

```
*Jared* eventually found the problems which were two in number:
1) $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username); <-- required a db connection $con in my case
2) $count = mysql_num_rows($userData); <-- required to pass the $result instead.
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: One  usually solves problems like this using debugging - step-by-step output of every variable and state until one can identify the exact place where things go wrong

Comment: Okay I did that and found out $count was coming to <1 so the script was dying there... Now I realised that username needed to have single quotes around it otherwise SQL thinks its a table right? I'm going to do that now...

Comment: yeah, but you seem to be doing that already? (= adding single quotes, that is)

Comment: that didn't work... please see the new edit of my post!

Comment: Note, in `validateUser()`, `$username` is not available in that scope. You need a `global $username;` as the first line in that function, or you need to pass it to `function validateUser($username) {}`.

Comment: Jared, please elaborate? There is a $username defined right at the top... why shouldn't it be in the scope of this function?

Comment: Agreed, though it might be a better idea to use a function parameter instead of a global.

Comment: See this example: http://codepad.org/e6XXrMER and read on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). The current `validateUser()` has only `$username` in the function-scope, so it has to be defined *within* the function, or brought in somehow (argument, global keyword).

Comment: And this is just my opinion, but `validateUser()` isn't an appropriate name for that function, as it's name suggests it actually performs some kind of validation ("The username is a certain length", etc.). Instead, it's really a `function setUserSession($username) {}`. At least in my humble opinion.

Comment: @user1031312 - What is the full script for your query that's not working? Where does `$username` come from in that script? I'm wondering if you used `$_SESSION['username']` instead of `$username`, if it would work.

Comment: Thats guys I appreciate your time scrutinizing my code. Does anyone see my current problem though? The script is exiting before validateUser() is even being called (and i've updated that to pass a parameter now) .. it exits on if($count<1). @Jared its in the post before the EDIT: its from $_POST

Comment: $username = $_POST['username']; 
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

Comment: You know what, this: `mysql_real_escape_string($username);` needs a valid [`mysql_connect()` link identifier](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) available. What happens if you move your database connection parts *above* that line? Or move that line below the connection scripts/function calls? It will return `FALSE` on error, which would print as `''` (empty) in a string.

Comment: Ahh, you're right and now that brings up a non-blank user name, in fact the correct user name, thanks so much!!! Strangely though, the $count is still blank? I guess that needs a link too.. EDIT: No the $count is still blank ... :(

Comment: You need to pass the return of `mysql_query()` to [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php), not the return of `mysql_fetch_assoc()`. So, `$count = mysql_num_rows($result);`.

Comment: You can use this: `$count = count($userData);` since you've already extracted the data from the db.

Comment: Thats it!! Its working now. Lol. Thanks so much! and thanks to everyone else too :).

Comment: This is actually Jared's solution, but since he didn't post an answer, I upvoted all his comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's with this part?

```
for ($x=0; $x<1; $x++) {
  $salt = $userData['salt'];
  $hashed_pass = $userData['password'];
}
```

Do a var_dump of `$userData`.

EDIT

```
function validateUser($username) {
    session_regenerate_id ();
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $username;
}
```

and near the bottom:

```
if ($hash != $hashed_pass) {
    header('Location: log_in.php5?error=1');
    die();
} else {
    validateUser($username);
}
```

Comment: I'm new to PHP and this is the only way I previously knew of extracting results from a mysql_query ! $count is supposed to be 1 so i put 1 instead of $count. Please give me an example of a var_dump

Comment: But you're not using the `$x` variable in the loop, and it loops only once, so the `for` part is unnecessary here. Example: `var_dump($userData);`

Comment: I understand for loops and I know i'm looping once. I don't understand how in PHP you can loop over many SQL results with the same variable without any index and it shows all the results e.g. if it had 10 users the $userData['salt'] var would go through all 10. But thats a different question.

Comment: See this short tutorial: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlselect.php it should be really helpful.

Comment: Thanks for that, you've probably saved me the big hassle I would've had after I solved this - but the problem still remains that $username is empty when I try to output it.